# Mysql data extraction

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have a table called deals, it has records like this for example

```
id deal_ref objectname  status
1  1234      tom        correct
2  1234      tom        correct
3  1234      jerry      wrong
4  1234      tom        correct
```

I need to identify all latest deals where the status is "correct for example, but the last entry(row 4) must meet the following criteria, where the Max ID is equal to the deal_ref and the status is correct

I tried this

```
select  distinct deal_ref, deal_status
from    dealv1 d 
where   d.deal_ref = max(id) 
and  d.deal_status  = 'Prospect'  
and date_created between '2022-11-02 00:00:00' and '2022-11-04 00:00:00'
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() .. AS rn` in CTE and `WHERE rn=1` in outer query.

Comment: d.deal_status  = 'Prospect'  isn't going to find anything from your sample data..and annoyingly there is no date_created in the sample, representative sample data should be  provided.

Answer (score 0):

You use other names in your SQL than in the table (deal_status, date_created).
Nevertheless try do it the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM dealv1 d
WHERE status = 'correct'
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

i don´t get exactly what you are trying to do with the maxID. You just want the one row where deal_ref=max(id) and status is correct?
Then add

```
AND deal_ref = (SELECT MAX(id) from dealv1)
```

after 'correct' from the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

Guys the query below worked, but its displaying multiple deal_refs that has the same deal_ref, for example 2 rows below each other with deal_ref 1234 twice.

```
SELECT *
FROM dealv1 d
WHERE status = 'correct'
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```